# Accurate bumper simulation

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi!

I'm trying to simulate a bumper as 'real' as possible. I would like to have the 3D model of the bumper move when it bumps into an object and then measure the position or even have a switch inside the bumper to trigger a message with the bumper information.

Is this possible? Is there a special type of joint that I should use? I want to use ROS, so I can't use the latests Gazebo versions.

Any help is appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6168/accurate-bumper-simulation/) by [tulku](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/791/tulku/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-05-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi

You can use the ros bumper plugin: [link](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins#Bumper)

An example at [link text](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5355/adding-ros-integrated-contact-sensors/)

Hope it helps!

---

Originally posted by [peshala](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/111/peshala/) with karma: 197 on 2014-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tulku](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/791/tulku/) on 2014-05-12**:
Thank you very much for your answer! I'm having the same problem as Gxav. I get an empty state message.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You could attach the bumper to the robot base using a slider joint. The bumper will move, and you could measure the motion using a model plugin.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2014-05-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tulku](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/791/tulku/) on 2014-05-12**:
Thank you! I'll try to get the simple bumper working first and then change it to use the slider joint, which looks like what I wanted to do.